# Angular Datepicker MinDate disabling one day behind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the Angular Bootstrap Datepicker and I'm setting the min-date attribute like this:

```
<input type="text" class="" uib-datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" 
       show-button-bar="false" ng-model="vm.date" ng-change="vm.DateChanged()" 
       min-date="vm.minDate" date-disabled="vm.disabledDates(date,mode)" />
```

Where `minDate` is set in my controller as: (as shown in console)

```
vm.minDate = '2016-02-19'
```

However, my calendar is coming up with **February 18** available as well:

[image: calendar]

Why is this happenning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This datepicker [uses the browser timezone for dates](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2952#issuecomment-63123945). There is [an open request](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4837) to provide UTC support or to provide some way to set a specific timezone or even better, to use dates without considering timezones at all.

As we can't scape from that yet, you can solve this by using an UTC date format:

```
vm.minDate = '2016-02-19T00:00:00Z'
```

In this GitHub [thread](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2952), people suggests other solutions, like [this one](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2952#issuecomment-121696576) which sets a directive to use UTC by correcting the date with the timezone offset:

```
ngModelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
    var date = new Date(value);

    if (isNaN(date) || (value == null)) {
        return value;  // needed for null/empty/undefined values
    }

    date.setMinutes(date.getTimezoneOffset());  // forces the "local" version of the date to match the intended UTC date

    return date;  // yes, this is a Date object being applied to the $viewValue...don't judge, it works!
});
```

**Edit**: I've created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1ZtvLZO7U6jqZKqNNE4?p=preview) to test this. What I've used:

```
var date = new Date('2016-02-19');
date.setMinutes(date.getTimezoneOffset());
$scope.minDate = date;
```

Comment: my date does not have any time on it. and even when I tried to set it explicitly like you suggested, it did not work. the calendar still a day behind

Comment: @MB Any Javascript Date object has a time on it - if you don't set it yourself, it defaults to 00:00:00.000

Comment: @MB, I've updated my answer with a Plunker. Its working for me. Look at the **example.js** file.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Its working! Not sure what was wrong with mine. I was using a string with the date. I guess it was parsing it wrong...??